# extract 10 digits from a string

Tags: sed, awk, grep

The following command is working as expected and showing me the highlighted results where it finds 10 digit number.

```
# grep '[0-9]\{10\}' test.csv
0987654321,Raka,Nr Man  Informatics,Bm ,Bangalore,,26 - 12 - 2010
Rajesh  Patel,No 9999 Part Road  Town  Airlines Bangalore Cell-9702977479,Crv,Bangalore,560051,19 - 7 - 2013
```

What I need to do is to "extract" that digit to the beginning of the line. It should look something like this...

```
0987654321,0987654321,Raka,Nr Man  Informatics,Bm ,Bangalore,,26 - 12 - 2010
9702977479,Rajesh  Patel,No 9999 Part Road  Town  Airlines Bangalore Cell-9702977479,Crv,Bangalore,560051,19 - 7 - 2013
```

update:

If no 10 digit number is found then the row should be appended with some dummy data for e.g. 0000000000 (for consistency purpose)

Comment: Do you need `grep -o` to return just the match? It do you actually want the number repeated?

Comment: The number should be repeated at the beginning so that I can process it using database.

Comment: Can your file contain, say, an 11-digit number and if so what should be done with that - ignored or treated the same as 10-digit or truncated to 10 digits or...?

Comment: 10 digits to the right. Usually the first 2 are country code if the number is > 10

Comment: OK, see my updated answer. What about the email comment you made elsethread? You should update your sample input and expected output to include that plus any other edge cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using sed:

```
 sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{10\}\).*/\1,&/' input
```

*Gives:*

```
0987654321,0987654321,Raka,Nr Man  Informatics...
9702977479,Rajesh  Patel,No 9999 Part Road  To...
```

And this one will add 10 0's in case no 10 digit number is found:

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{10\}\).*/\1,&/;/[0-9]\{10\}/!s/^/0000000000,/' input
```

Comment: Yes. This is correct. I just noticed that the data also have email and that should be listed after the cell number followed by comma or pipe. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for `\>` word delimiter:

```
$ cat file
0987654321,Raka,Nr Man  Informatics,Bm ,Bangalore,,26 - 12 - 2010
Rajesh  Patel,No 9999 Part Road  Town  Airlines Bangalore Cell-9702977479,Crv,Bangalore,560051,19 - 7 - 2013
foo,bar
long,num,12345678901234

$ gawk -v OFS="," '{print (match($0,/[[:digit:]]{10}\>/) ? substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) : "0000000000"), $0 }' file
0987654321,0987654321,Raka,Nr Man  Informatics,Bm ,Bangalore,,26 - 12 - 2010
9702977479,Rajesh  Patel,No 9999 Part Road  Town  Airlines Bangalore Cell-9702977479,Crv,Bangalore,560051,19 - 7 - 2013
0000000000,foo,bar
5678901234,long,num,12345678901234
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.*\([0-9]\{10\}\).*$\)/\2,\1/'
```

Now tested and working. Note that I have two sets of capturing groups - one around the entire expression (this is the first capturing group and is referred to as `\1`), and a second (inner) one that wraps around the ten digit number, referred to as `\2`.

If you want only the last ten digits of a "possibly longer than 10" number, you can do

```
sed 's/\(.*\([0-9]\{10\}\)[^0-9].*$\)/\2,\1/'
```

which makes sure that "the next thing after 10 digits is not a digit (and thus finds the last ten).

Comment: Not quite. It has several errors. Not escaped parentheses nor curly braces. There aren't two groups used in the replacement part and you need a quantifier before finding the ten digits. Something like this will be still closer: `sed 's/^\(.*\)\([0-9]\{10\}\)/\2,\1\2/'`

Comment: @birei - thanks for the feedback. You are right. Fixed now (not quite your way but tested and working)